# Abstract Vectors

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, vector-calculus

Is there a way to deal with abstract vectors in the following sense:

Say I have a function `f[y]`. Now I want to evaluate `D[f[x'b], x_j]`, where `x` and `b` are k $\times$ 1 vectors with `x_j` and `b_j` as typical elements. Then Mathematica would give me: `D[f[x'b], x_j] = f'(.)*b_j`.

Can *Mathematica* deal with vectors in this way?